# Uploading an Android Executable to a website in java

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to upload the android executables that are on my system to a website.

Here is the website link :"http://onlinemd5.com/"

Present Scenario:

1)The website has already got a "choose" option where we can upload the files.

2)The website calculates the md5 checksum of the uploaded files on clicking the
  compare option

Expected Output:

1) I am looking at a scenario where i can interact with the website through an API through JAVA

2) The java program  should itself click the choose button and upload the file and return the displayed output back.

I have gone through an API called "HTMLUnit" which serves the task.However,There are hardly any resources that i could relate my "Expected Output " with

I would be happy to hear any suggestions,which would help in accomplishing my goal.

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of file are you trying to hash and why do you have php tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need this website you can calculate md5 of file using java like below

```
    MessageDigest dig = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    DigestInputStream stream = new DigestInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/file")),dig);
    while(stream.read() != -1);
    byte[] digest = dig.digest();
    String md5 = new BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16);
    System.out.print(md5);
```

Comment: I have tried it before..but the md5 i got is different from the actual md5 which i found during installing the executable :)